# Using logitech c270 to do object detection

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

May I know is that any existing package or project I can use as reference or tutorial  to learn use webcam to detect the object?

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Kinetic in my laptop

I really appreciate any of yours advises and suggestions.

Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297209/using-logitech-c270-to-do-object-detection/) by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2018-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can take a look into [object_recognition](http://wiki.ros.org/object_recognition) and [find_object_2d](http://wiki.ros.org/find_object_2d).

These projects might be of help too: [tensorflow_object_detector](https://github.com/osrf/tensorflow_object_detector),  [yolo_object_detector](https://github.com/osrf/yolo_object_detector), [ros_people_object_detection_tensorflow](https://github.com/cagbal/ros_people_object_detection_tensorflow)

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2018-07-13**:
Hi, thank you for answering my question. Actually I had found the find_object_2d package, but the provided information actually is kind of confuses to me.....did you know any other better website to lean how to source the package?

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2018-07-13**:
for example, like I had source the OpenCV in my laptop, so do I  still need to source the vision-opencv package?

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-07-16**:
[vision_opencv](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv) is for interfacing ROS with OpenCV and you should build it yourself only if you want to use OpenCV2.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-07-16**:
The problem is that vision_opencv provides the cv_bridge package. The recent upgrade of the opencv3 package breaks the published cv_bridge package so you will need to rebuild cv_bridge properly. This [answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/262329/how-to-install-cv_bridge/) may be of help.

**Comment by [Zero](https://answers.ros.org/users/26215/zero/) on 2018-07-19**:
Thank you so much! I will try it first!